# When should I use a this.context vs Consumer in the New Context API in React?

Tags: reactjs

There are two styles for using the context data in the Child components: `this.context` and using the `<myContext.Consumer>{(contextData) => {return(<div>{myContextData}</div>}}</myContext.Consumer>`

when should I use the former vs latter?

Comment: it can be used in both ways but with this.context you can consume a single context.
check context api https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 6):

There are not two but three ways to use context in v16.8.0 and above. The choice of which one you should use depends upon your use case.

The first one i.e using `static contextType` is the simplest of the two to use which allows you to use context throughout your class component. You can acchieve the same behaviour using render props pattern but then you have to wrap your component within another functional component.

So the choice, although a matter of personal preference and wouldn't impact performance of debugging much is simple to make.

- If you want to make use of just one `context` within the component, you can make use of `static contextType` to define it.
- However, if you have more than one context which you want your component to use, then you can't achieve that with the first pattern,so you have to make use of `render props` pattern

An example of the above is say you are using a ThemeProvider and your component just uses that you can write it simply as below using first pattern

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   ...
}
MyComponnet.contextType = ThemeContext;
export default MyComponent
```

with render prop pattern you would need to write it as below given you want to use context outside of render method too

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   ...
}

export default (props) => (
    <ThemContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => <MyComponent {...props} context={context} /> 
     <ThemeContext.Consumer>
)
```

However say you want to use two context within MyComponent ie. say a ThemeContext and ShortCutContext to listen to keyboard shortcuts you would write it using render props like below

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   ...
}

export default (props) => (
    <ShortcutContext.Consumer>
        {(sCon) => (
         <ThemContext.Consumer>
            {(tCon) => <MyComponent {...props} themeContext={tCon} shortcutContext={sCon} /> 
         <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        )}
    </ShortcutContext.Consumer>

)
```

There is a third way which is `useContext`, which allows you to use context within functional components using hooks pattern. If you are writing your App with hooks, you can make use of `useContext` which allows you to have multiple contexts within your App too

You can use multiple contexts using `useContext` as below

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const shortcutContext = useContext(ShortcutContext);
   const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);
   ...
}
```